# How to remove comments without regex

Tags: java

So, my assignment was to remove all /* insert_comment */ from the string entered. I figured out how to do it with one block comment, but I have to do it with multiple block comments in one string.

I have an idea on how to do it, but I am not sure how to implement it into my code. I have tried searching, but most solutions involve regular expressions, which I am not allowed to use.

and btw, the snippet does not run

```html
public static String removeComments(String s)
int index = 0;
String new = "";


while (index <= s.length())
{
if( s.charAt(index) = (I don't know how to do this) "/*"
String temp = s.substring(0, index)
index++;
[somehow makes it loop until it reaches */]
new = new.concat(temp)

else
index++

  return new;
```

yeah, this doesn't make much sense, but I am confused. I am also sick right now and can't think straight, but I want to get this done so I don't fall further behind than I already am. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: `if( s.charAt(index) = (I don't know how to do this) "/*"` is essentially the same as `if (s.charAt(index) == '/' && s.charAt(index+1) == '*')`. It's also the same as `if(s.substring(index, index + 2) == "/*")`. You will of course need to alter your bounds, i.e. `while (index < s.length - 1)`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know there will be more solutions, but this one should definitely work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String stringWithComments = "mystring   /*this is a comment*/";

        String comment = stringWithComments.substring(stringWithComments.indexOf("/*") + 2 , stringWithComments.indexOf("*/")); // +2 because the String will start from "/*"
        System.out.println(comment);    // this prints out the extracted comment

        System.out.println(stringWithComments.replace("/*" + comment + "*/" , "")); //replaces your /*comment*/ with an empty string

    }
```

**EDIT:**

the output:

```
this is a comment
mystring
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringRemover {

    public String remove(String originalText){

        String text = originalText, comment = "";
        int index = 0;
        while( index != -1){

            comment = text.substring(text.indexOf("/*"),text.indexOf("*/")+2);
            //System.out.println("comment :"+comment);
            text = text.replace(comment, "");

            index = text.indexOf("/*");
        }
        return text;
    }
}
class RunTest
{
    public static void main(String cp[]){

        String sampleText = "This is Line1\n /* Comment1 */ \nThis is Line2 \n /* Comment2 */ " +
                "\nThis is Line3 \n /* Comment3 */ \nEnd";
        StringRemover sr = new StringRemover();
        String result = sr.remove(sampleText);
        System.out.println("Before Removing comments :\n"+sampleText);
        System.out.println("\nAfter Removing comments :\n"+result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before Removing comments :
This is Line1
 /* Comment1 */ 
This is Line2 
 /* Comment2 */ 
This is Line3 
 /* Comment3 */ 
End

After Removing comments :
This is a Line1

This is Line2 

This is Line3 

End
```